# Слишком медленно проигрывается анимация

Tags: livewallpaper, android, java

Всем привет.

Я тут уже долго мучаюсь с такой проблемой. В общем, у меня есть 120 картинок, я хочу сделать из них покадровую анимацию для живых обоев. Анимация проигрывается, все круто, но играет очень медленно, примерно один кадр в секунду.

Я уже выяснил, в чем причина,  это из-за того, что я декодирую картинку каждый раз, когда вывожу ее. Но теперь вопрос, как мне сперва декодировать все картинки, а потом выводить? Пробовал много вариантов, но все они были тщетны...

Вот мой код живых обоев, может, кто подскажет, как мне исправить эту ошибку?

```
public class WallpaperSer extends WallpaperService {

    static final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new WallpaperSerEngine();
    }

    class WallpaperSerEngine extends Engine  {
        private boolean mVisible;
        private float mScaleX;
        private float mScaleY;
        private Bitmap icon;
        private Runnable diwaliImg;

        int i = 0;
        int[] pirates = {
                R.drawable.final_0001, R.drawable.final_0002, R.drawable.final_0003, R.drawable.final_0004,
                R.drawable.final_0005, R.drawable.final_0006, R.drawable.final_0007, R.drawable.final_0008,
                R.drawable.final_0009, R.drawable.final_0010, R.drawable.final_0011, R.drawable.final_0012,
                R.drawable.final_0013, R.drawable.final_0014, R.drawable.final_0015, R.drawable.final_0016,
                R.drawable.final_0017, R.drawable.final_0018, R.drawable.final_0019, R.drawable.final_0020,
                R.drawable.final_0021, R.drawable.final_0022, R.drawable.final_0023, R.drawable.final_0024,
                R.drawable.final_0025, R.drawable.final_0026, R.drawable.final_0027, R.drawable.final_0028,
                R.drawable.final_0029, R.drawable.final_0030, R.drawable.final_0031, R.drawable.final_0032,
                R.drawable.final_0033, R.drawable.final_0034, R.drawable.final_0035, R.drawable.final_0036,
                R.drawable.final_0037, R.drawable.final_0038, R.drawable.final_0039, R.drawable.final_0040,
                R.drawable.final_0041, R.drawable.final_0042, R.drawable.final_0043, R.drawable.final_0044,
                R.drawable.final_0045, R.drawable.final_0046, R.drawable.final_0047, R.drawable.final_0048,
                R.drawable.final_0049, R.drawable.final_0050, R.drawable.final_0051, R.drawable.final_0052,
                R.drawable.final_0053, R.drawable.final_0054, R.drawable.final_0065, R.drawable.final_0056,
                R.drawable.final_0057, R.drawable.final_0058, R.drawable.final_0059, R.drawable.final_0060,
                R.drawable.final_0061, R.drawable.final_0062, R.drawable.final_0063, R.drawable.final_0064,
                R.drawable.final_0065, R.drawable.final_0066, R.drawable.final_0067, R.drawable.final_0068,
                R.drawable.final_0069, R.drawable.final_0070, R.drawable.final_0071, R.drawable.final_0072,
                R.drawable.final_0073, R.drawable.final_0074, R.drawable.final_0075, R.drawable.final_0076,
                R.drawable.final_0077, R.drawable.final_0078, R.drawable.final_0079, R.drawable.final_0080,
                R.drawable.final_0081, R.drawable.final_0082, R.drawable.final_0083, R.drawable.final_0084,
                R.drawable.final_0085, R.drawable.final_0086, R.drawable.final_0087, R.drawable.final_0088,
                R.drawable.final_0089, R.drawable.final_0090, R.drawable.final_0091, R.drawable.final_0092,
                R.drawable.final_0093, R.drawable.final_0094, R.drawable.final_0095, R.drawable.final_0096,
                R.drawable.final_0097, R.drawable.final_0098, R.drawable.final_0099, R.drawable.final_0100,
                R.drawable.final_0101, R.drawable.final_0102, R.drawable.final_0103, R.drawable.final_0104,
                R.drawable.final_0105, R.drawable.final_0106, R.drawable.final_0107, R.drawable.final_0108,
                R.drawable.final_0109, R.drawable.final_0110, R.drawable.final_0111, R.drawable.final_0112,
                R.drawable.final_0113, R.drawable.final_0114, R.drawable.final_0115, R.drawable.final_0116,
                R.drawable.final_0117, R.drawable.final_0118, R.drawable.final_0119, R.drawable.final_0120
        };

        WallpaperSerEngine() {
            diwaliImg = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    drawFrame();
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder){
            super.onCreate(holder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(diwaliImg);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            mVisible = visible;
            if (visible) {
                drawFrame();
            } else {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(diwaliImg);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
            drawFrame();
            mScaleX = width / (1f * icon.getWidth());
            mScaleY = height / (1f * icon.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            mVisible = false;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(diwaliImg);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset, float xStep,float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {
            drawFrame();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        private void drawFrame() {
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (c != null) {
                    drawPirate(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null)
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(diwaliImg);
            if (mVisible) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(diwaliImg, 1000 / 25);
            }
        }

        private void drawPirate(Canvas c) {
            icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), pirates[i]);
            i++;
            if (i == 120) {
                i = 0;
            }
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            c.scale(mScaleX, mScaleY);
            c.drawBitmap(icon, matrix, null);
            icon.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/231787/  
http://habrahabr.ru/post/137275/

Comment: Ну единственное, что я подчерпнул с этих статей, - это используйте AndEngine для обоев. Это не решение моей проблемы, не хочу юзать движок...

Comment: @dajver, а придется, если хотите, чтобы работало с нормальной скоростью. И еще не вылетало с OutOfMemory. Так не бывает, что "хочу, чтобы работало, но не хочу ничего делать"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Попробуйте принудительно задать частоту обновления кадров. Точно не помню, но раньше искал по тегам "surfaceholder set framerate".
2. Каждый раз декодировать изображение перед отрисовкой - ужас! Декодирование занимает довольно много времени. Если изображения не меют огромного разрешения, то можно попробовать декодировать все сразу в какой-нибудь массив Bitmap[], а потом брать уже декодированные данные оттуда. Советую использовать конфиг RGB_565, если изображения без альфа-канала и вы желаете занимать не так много памяти. Если так будет выкидывать OutOfMemoryException, то лучше сделать кэширование по частям: например, создаётся массив Bitmap с вместимостью 10 объектов и заполняется первой партией изображений, потом они берутся оттуда. Как только было отрисовано 10е изображение, то надо загрузить следующую пачку картинок и так далее.

**Update** Посмотрел образцы изображений и сразу же назрела идея. Вам нужно как-то вырезать фон (то есть ту часть, которая на протяжении всей анимации не меняется) и держать его в битмапе с конфигом `RGB_565` (так как пррзрачности не будет или она всё равно перекроется), чтобы расходовалось меньше ОЗУ. Далее из всех кадров вырезаете все части, которые изменяются. Лучше всего просто сохранять куски из середины одинакового размера (например, `768х512`, а это уже не `768х1024`, так что расход памяти точно будет меньше) и держите их в битмапе с конфигом `RGB_565` или `ARGB_8888`, если в вырезанных частях будет прозрачность. Потом можно провернуть кэширование по частям из п2 с вырезанными кусками. А дальше просто - сначала рисуем фон, а потом кусок анимации посередине.

Comment: Делал вот так, падало с аут оф мемори
`pirateIcons = new Bitmap[pirates.length];
for(int k = 0; k <= pirates.length; k++)
      pirateIcons[k] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), pirates[k]);`
а вот второй вариант ваш с запоминанием 10 элементов мне нравится, но я не знаю как сделать такое

картинки у меня размером 720х1280

Comment: @dajver, выложите куда-нибудь 2-3 картинки, пожалуйста. Я уверен, что там есть одинаковая часть и всё можно оптимизировать.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61086119/drawable.rar вот вам 5 картинок если так лучше будет.

Comment: @dajver, обновил ответ.

Comment: Не получится отделить, это нарезка из видео...

Comment: других идей не будет?

Comment: @dajver, если мне не изменяет память, то вы можете открыть видео (а не кадры) с помощью `MediaPlayer` и выводить изображение на `SurfaceView`.